# Sort numbers using special function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this way of sorting  the array:

```js
const arr = [0,6,8,7,1,2,3];

const sortBubble = () => {
  for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
        const temp = arr[j];
         arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
         arr[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(sortBubble())
```

Also this function:

```js
const arr = [0,6,8,7,1,2,3];

const sortBubble = () => {
  for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
         arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
         arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
      }
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(sortBubble())
```

I can't understand, why in the last function i get a different result than in the first function. How you can see in the last function i didn't use: `temp` variable, but anyway in my vision `temp` and `arr[j]` should be equal and i expect in both function the result as in first function, but last one has a different result. 
 Why the last function acts different if i don't use `temp` variable?

Comment: `arr[j] = arr[j + 1]` overwrites `arr[j]`. `arr[j + 1] = arr[j];` in the next line is equivalent to `arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1];`

Comment: The values in the array are numbers and not objects, that means that when you assign them a value it is the actual value and not the reference to the object (it is not an object). This means that you must save the current value in temp var and if not you overwrite it the original value will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a closer look at your second code you are doing the following:

```
      if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
         arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
         arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
      }
```

So you set `arr[j]` equal to `arr[j+1]`, the second line makes no change to the array, as you have over-written `arr[j]`'s value

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap items in an array, you have to use a temporary variable as a buffer to store one of the two values you're swapping:

In your second example, let's say you have this array:

```
const arr = [5, 6];
```

Now let's say `j` equals `0`: `arr[j] = arr[j + 1]` will make your array become: `[6, 6]`

Then you execute `arr[j + 1] = arr[j]` which gives `[6, 6]` and you cannot retrieve `5` anymore as there is no more reference on it.

Answer (score 0):

`arr[j] = arr[j + 1]` overwrites `arr[j]`. `arr[j + 1] = arr[j];` in the next line is equivalent to `arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1];`. You can avoid an explicit `temp` variable with

```
if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
  [arr[j], arr[j + 1]] = [arr[j + 1], arr[j]];
}
```

but of course internally the temporary value has to be stored.

Example:

```js
const arr = [0,6,8,7,1,2,3];

const sortBubble = () => {
  for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
         [arr[j], arr[j + 1]] = [arr[j + 1], arr[j]];
      }
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(sortBubble())
```